# What are some good video lectures on DSGE modeling?

Tags: dsge

Are there any online resources on Dynamic Stochastic General Equilibrium models supplied with video lectures, which include theory and some practical examples of fitting models as well? I did not find anything like that in Google, but maybe there are some records from PhD courses or summer schools, which are hopefully available online?

Comment: Try this guy. It is has 3 series. Make sure you watch the third series because that is where he did estimation in DSGE. https://youtu.be/ZH-BRQaAaBU